# Twitter removed Share Counts - Whats the best solution?

Tags: api, twitter, share

Around *September 2015* **Twitter** removed the option to get the share count via their API. What is the **best solution** to overcome it and get the share counts ? is their a 3rd party plugin you recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://opensharecount.com, it gets you a drop-in replacement for the old API

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your plugin, because some have it built in now and some you need to sign up with a service and use their code.

This guide will show you how to get your counts back for all of the major ones: http://copytactics.com/tweet-counter

(Includes the official button, SumoMe, AddThis, AddToAny, Shareaholic, etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. This answer isn't really complete, basically it only provides a link. Link-only answers aren't the best ones: should the link ever become invalid, your answer would become useless. So please [edit] it and add at least a summary of what can be found there, so that your answer has a value independently of the link. Thank you!